# Good references for parallel programming in Mathematica

Tags: parallelization, reference-request

There are plenty of good references for all sorts of Mathematica programming:

- This forum is a great example for specific questions/"getting things done".
- Books like those by R.Maeder (esp. the now ancient "Programming in Mathematica"), Ruskeepa, Tam, Trott, Wagner, Wellin, etc are all excellent at presenting stuff in a more organized, thorough fashion.
- The built-in WRI documentation can be quite good (but that's not the case here, in my opinion).

Most of these books were published before parallel tools were a prominent feature in Mathematica.

While Stackexchange answers are great for getting specific things done quickly (same goes for the Mathematica Cookbook), it's not in the spirit of this site to provide a bottom-up, textbook-like explanation of a relatively broad subject as this is.

There are several lists of Mathematica-related references and links - most notably here [18](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice), but the few parallel computation topics therein are somewhat specific/narrow.

So the question is: do you know of books, or other well structured, thorough bottom-up discussions of parallel programming in Mathematica? Care to share your recommendations?

Answer (score 15):

Far from what you wish, here is a list of Roman Maeder's presentations
about parallel programming :

- "Discovering & Using Wolfram Language Kernels" (2015) [notebook](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/9298/)   ; [video](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=400&v=1478)
- Automatic Parallelism (2011) [notebook](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7970/")  ;  [video](http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=109&v=176)
- Experiences with Mainstream Parallel Computing (2009) [notebook](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7541/)
- Parallel computing in Mathematica 7 - Richard Gass (2009) [notebook](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7449/)
- Enhancements in Parallel Computing in Mathematica (2008) [notebook](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/7321/)
- Parallel Computing in Version 6 and Beyond (2007) [notebook](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6983/)
- Debugging and Profiling Parallel Programs (2006) [notebook](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6599/)
- Parallelization with Mathematica (2006) [notebook](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6487/)
- Parallel Experiments (2005) [notebook](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/5774/)
- The Parallel Computing Toolkit, Version 2 (2004) [notebook & PDF](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/5364/)
- The Parallel Computing Toolkit (2001) [notebook](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/4043/)
- Parallel Programming (1998) [notebook](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/357/)
- Parallel Processing (1997)
- Parallel Programming in Mathematica (1997)

**Edit**

- Performance of Massively Parallel Computations with the Wolfram Language (WTC Amsterdam 20 June 2017) *No link at the moment* (*30/09/2017*)

Answer (score 8):

One of the books that contain a detailed discussion about parallel computing is [The Mathematica Cookbook by Sal Mangano](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596520999). A quick google search reveals that there seems to be a pdf version available. Therefore, you might want to have a look at chapter 16 and see if it fits your needs.

Comment: haha, I wonder if I should downvote this post to protect the link.

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK the only recently published book that covers parallel programming is [Mathematica Beyond Mathematics](https://www.crcpress.com/Mathematica-Beyond-Mathematics-The-Wolfram-Language-in-the-Real-World/Leon/p/book/9781498796293) in sections 12.1-12.5.